# Company eclim: cannot complete at point

Tags: company-mode, java

#### What works

I have installed `emacs-eclim` and have it working in my Java buffers. For example, I can invoke `eclim-java-refactor-rename-symbol-at-point` or `eclim-java-show-documentation-for-current-element` and they behave as expected.

I can run `eclim-complete`, and I receive a list of correct completions in another buffer.

I evaluate something like `company-emacs-eclim--candidates "Object.")` in a java buffer, and I get a list of completion candidates.

Without any `eclim` backends, `company` also works as expected.

#### What doesn't work

Hoping to get `eclim` completion candidates in my Java buffers, I added the following lines to my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'company-emacs-eclim)
(company-emacs-eclim-setup)
```

However, I do not get eclim completions as expected. If I invoke `company-emacs-eclim` explicitly, I get the error `"Cannot complete at point"`, with the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Cannot complete at point")
  signal(error ("Cannot complete at point"))
  error("Cannot complete at point")
  company-begin-backend(company-emacs-eclim)
  company-emacs-eclim(interactive)
  ad-Orig-call-interactively(company-emacs-eclim record nil)
  call-interactively(company-emacs-eclim record nil)
  command-execute(company-emacs-eclim record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "company-emacs-eclim")
  smex-read-and-run(("toggle-debug-on-error" "company-emacs-eclim" ...))
  smex()
  ad-Orig-call-interactively(smex nil nil)
  call-interactively(smex nil nil)
```

#### Version information

`GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7)
 of 2014-03-07 on lamiak, modified by Debian`

`emacs-eclim 20150502.516`

Comment: Well if the answer wasn't solve, M-TAB is same as 'eclim-complete' for me and it is default key binding.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. Yes, `eclim-complete` works for me (see section "What works"). I get a list of completions in another buffer, and clicking on them inserts the completion (along with the annotation, which isn't too useful). What I'm trying to do here is integrate those completions with company (the typical way to do this is with `company-emacs-eclim`), so that the completion candidates appear in a dropdown automatically. Ideally it would also autocomplete without the annotation, and with yasnippet integration for inserting arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling `eclim-mode` when editing the file. That should bring up the completion automatically.

Comment: Adding `(eclim-mode)` to my java mode hooks did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Using company mode.  Won't complete at point, but completes everything else.